# Picasso tarda mucho en descargar las imágenes en mi app

Tags: android, android-fragment, picasso

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación con varios ImageButtton y para no cargar tanto la aplicación estoy usando Picasso y Xampp para llenarlos.
Lo que pasa esquema tarda mucho tiempo en poner las imágenes en sus correspondientes ImageButton. alguien sabe porque?

Aqui adjunto mi código.

```
public class SedeValencia extends Fragment {

private ImageButton ima1;
private ImageButton ima2;
private ImageButton ima3;
private ImageButton ima4;
private ImageButton ima5;
private ImageButton ima6;
private View v;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sede_valencia,container,false);

    ima1 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc1);
    ima2 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc2);
    ima3 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc3);
    ima4 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc4);
    ima5 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc5);
    ima6 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc6);



    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp/vlc/pasedi.jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima1);

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp/vlc/vidaiglevlc.jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima2);

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp/vlc/reunionesvlc.jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima3);

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp//vlc/ubivlc.jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima4);

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp/redesvlc.jpg" )
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima5);


    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema aquí puede ser:

- **tus imágenes son de tamaño considerable** y que su manejo en memoria provoca un gran consumo de recursos.
- Si el tamaño de tus imágenes es considerable y la velocidad de tu conexión es lenta, tardará más de lo común la descarga. .

Sin duda la solución es **optimizar las imágenes**

Aquí un tutorial: https://sites.google.com/site/ticvalcarcel/optimizacion-de-imagenes-para-internet/tamano-y-peso-de-las-imagenes